# Inheriting the equality comparer

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a Customer class.

```
public class Customer
{
    private string _id;
    private string _name;
    // some more properties follow
```

I am inheriting the EqualityComparer form MyEqualityComparer(of Customer).
This I am intending to use in LINQ queries.
MyEqualityComparer is intended for partial check between two objects.
If the customer.id and customer.name matches I treat the objects the equal.

```
public class MyComparer : System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public override bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        if (x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
    {
        return string.Concat(obj.Id,obj.Name).GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

I referred to  [generating hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340/how-do-i-generate-a-hashcode-from-a-byte-array-in-c).
I am little unsure about concatenating strings and using that as a hashcode.
Is this safe and sound what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this question on hashcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400) for a pretty simple way to return one hashcode based on multiple fields.

Having said that, I wouldn't derive from `EqualityComparer<T>` myself - I'd just implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` directly. I'm not sure what value `EqualityComparer<T>` is really giving you here, other than also implementing the non-generic `IEqualityComparer`.

A couple more things:

- You should handle nullity in Equals
- Your present Equals code can be simplified to:

  ```
  return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name;
  ```

A fuller implementation of Equals might be:

```
public override bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (x == null || y == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name;
}
```

Comment: Small bug - you need to cast x and y to object before comparing with null.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147

Comment: @Thracx: Only if you've also overloaded the `==` operator, and done so in a way which doesn't handle this.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer using three `return`s instead of one returnable logical expression?

Comment: @NetMage: Only preference on the day :) Personally I like the conditional operator, but I know some people find it harder to read.

Comment: I was thinking you don't need a conditional operator, just `&&` and `||` :)

Comment: @NetMage: I suspect that would end being significantly harder to read, to be honest. I could work out the expression, but I don't have the energy - feel free to add it as a comment and then we can compare the readability...

Comment: It would look like: `public override bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y) => object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name);`

Comment: @NetMage: Yup, that would do it. I think the separation of the different "kinds" of results improves readability, but I certainly accept that that's subjective.

Answer (score 3):

You should see it from the perspective of possible "collisions", e.g. when two different objects get the same hash code. This could be the case with such pairs as "1,2any" and "12, any", the values in the pairs being "id" and "name". If this is not possible with your data, you're good to go. Otherwise you can change it to something like:

```
return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Name.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: don't forget to null check Id and Name

Comment: Using an XOR creates collisions in quite a few situations, unfortunately. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-systemobjectgethashcode#263416. It may well be okay in the case of Name/ID, but it's not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper (fantastic refactoring plugin from JetBrains) thinks it should be:

```
public override int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return ((obj.Id != null ? obj.Id.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) 
            ^ (obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

I have to admit I almost always just let Resharper generate the equality and hash code implementations for me. I've tested their implementation a great deal and found it to be as good if not better than anything I'd write by hand. So I'll usually take the implementation I don't have to type.

Comment: Any reason for picking 397 other than prime ?

Comment: I think it is just meant to be big enough to put the first part of the hashcode in the higher bits of the end result. Resharper used to use 29. I can't say I know if there is a solid theory or if it was just chosen through experiement.