# Equal but not interchangeable

Tags: c#, equality

I have two objects that are something like this:

```
class Container {
    public HashSet<Item> Items { get; }
}

class Item {
    public Container Parent { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Every `Item` instance must belong to a `Container` instance, and there is a one-to-many relationship between the two that is always kept in sync at both ends.

I am now faced with implementing a method that compares two instances of `Item` to see if their `Value1` and `Value2` values match.  The method will **not** take into consideration the `Parent` value since each pair of instances I compare definitely differ on this value, so doing so would make the method I am implementing useless since it would then have the same result (`false`) as the `object.ReferenceEquals` method.

My question is as follows.  Should I implement this method as the object's `public override bool Equals( object obj )` method (along with `GetHashCode`)?  Or does the fact that it ignores its `Parent` property preclude me from doing so?  Why or why not?  An alternative idea I have is to just implement it as `public bool EqualsIgnoreParent( Item other )` which does not override anything; I could then call it from a custom comparer.

Comment: It can get kind of messy when you have value equality on a mutable object that you put into a `HashSet` because to operate properly the hash code must not change once it has been added to the set.

Comment: I prefer implementing an `IEqualityComparer` for mutable objects instead of overriding `Equals`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yup, that's what I did.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [mikez's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071372/equal-but-not-interchangeable#comment26447583_18071372) and Eric Lippert's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx), I found out that I shouldn't override `Item`'s `Equals` or `GetHashCode` methods since `Item`'s instances are mutable and added to a `HashSet`.

Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752155/122781), I decided to separate the two concepts of equality.

1. **Identity.** I did *not* override `Item`'s `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.  I left those methods as they are in `object`.  That's what the `HashSet` will use.
2. **Equivalence.** I created a public singleton class called `ValueComparer` that's nested within `Item` and implements `IEqualityComparer<Item>`.  This is where I put the comparison logic that I describe in my question.

Comment: One nice thing about `IEqualityComparer<Item>` is that `HashSet<T>`, `Dictionary<K,V>` etc. have constructor overloads that allow you to use them.

Comment: I prefer deriving from `EqualityComparer<T>` instead of implementing `IEqualityComparer<Item>` directly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What advantage do you find in `EqualityComparer<T>`?  Perhaps if you read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5707347/122781) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/340526/122781) then you'll change your mind.

Comment: Doesn't gain much, but you get an implementation of the non-generic `IEqualityComparer` interface for free. But it doesn't have significant downsides either. So it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Where in the framework can I pass in a non-generic `IEqualityComparer`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to implement IEquatable. so i suggest you just overloads Euqals(object other) with Euqals(Item other), while overwrites Equals(object other) by calling Equals(Item other).

of course, make GetHashCode return -1 always to force the equality comparison to be done via Equals.here is an explain of why need to overwrite GetHashCode method - [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement this with Equals and GetHashCode, **as long as Value1 and Value2 don't change or your hash is independent from any change**. (otherwise Collections using your HashCode won't work)

Additionally, you could reduce the Item class to the basic members

```cs
class Item {
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

and maintain the relation in an additional dictionary: (which would be efficient, if you implement GetHashCode correctly)

```
Dictionary<Item, Container> ContainersOfItems;
```

Comment: Regarding your second idea, I can't see replacing the `Parent` property with a static dictionary as an improvement. I think the opposite; it would complicate the code without practical benefit.

Comment: Maintaining lists on both side of the relationship already complicates the code due to redundancy ;) the benefit would be, that an

Comment: ... unavailable field can't have an effect on any equality logic. Thus gaining safety, losing flexibility, simplicity and readability. Same trade off as in statically typed languages.
You could of course hide the static dictionary behind a Parent property.

Comment: If the bi-directionality is redundant then why do you suggest the static dictionary which would be equally as "redundant"?  Obviously, it serves a purpose.  All of the fields in my example are potentially "unavailable" (notice the setters are public), not just `parent`. By putting it in a static dictionary, you are just changing the backing store such that a dictionary look-up would unnecessarily be required.

Comment: I suggested it, because it makes it harder to implement Equals the wrong way. 
As another answers said: "Don't do it, unless you are 100% sure that the Parent member NEVER makes any difference".
Without a "Parent" there won't be any discussion about it.
Additionally, regarding object oriented decomposition: If the "value" of an item does not depend on its parent, why including it?

Comment: Of course, it depends on your style: OOP style, decomposition style, architecture style. Sometimes doubly linked lists, tree nodes with an explicit parent field, or unnormalized database tables make sense. Mostly because of performance reasons: Trading memory for speed, or just for better code readibility in your algorithm.

Comment: I agree it would make it harder - to implement it any way at all, that is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it might be more meaningful to split Item so it looks something like:

```
class Container<TContent> {
    public HashSet<Item<TContent>> Items { get; }
}

class Item<TContent> {
    public Container Parent;
    public TContent Content;
}
```

If you do that, then you can define a type to hold your content which has an `Equals` method suitable for that type, and initialize your `HashSet` with an `IEqualityComparer<Item<TConcent>>` which bases equality upon each `Item<TContent>`'s `Content` field.

Comment: I just finished implementing the solution.  Modifying the object model would have been heavy handed and wasn't necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do it, unless you are 100% sure that the Parent member NEVER makes any difference. There might be many use cases you don't thought of, (what if you need to put items from 2 containers in a single Dictionary?) so i recommend to stick to the design. If by definition equality is determined only by other members, go for it. Otherwise, not.
You can always write case-specific equality logic later. Remember that `Dictionary`, `List`, `HashSet` and other collecctions allow you to define a custom `IEqualityComparer`.
There's an another option, but be very careful. Override both methods, but make `GetHashCode` more tolerant than `Equals`, that means, make unequal objects have the same hash code, and NOT the opposite. Make `GetHashCode` ignore the Parent member, but not `Equals`. it won't harm anything, and then if you want to ignore the Parent member in dictionaries, write an `IEqualityComparer` that compares them the same way like `GetHashCode`.

Comment: `An option is to override only GetHashCode` You should always either override both equals and gethashcode or neither, never just one.  It's important that they both have the same semantic meaning.

Comment: As i saw dictionary implementations, `GetHashCode` is used to calculate a starting search point within the dictionary. From this point the dict searches the item by invoking `Equals`. Its NOT necassary for the hash code to be unique, as the final equality check is made only by `Equals`.

Comment: Of course not, but it is important for both `Equals` as well as `GetHashCode` to be based on the same concept of equality.  If two objects are equal but have a different hash code because the `Equals` method uses value equality and the `GetHashCode` is based on reference equality (or vice versa) the dictionaries break down; it all of a sudden becomes possible to add multiple equal keys, or it will say an item doesn't exist when it does, etc.

Comment: Not both ways. If 2 different objects has the same hash code it's ok, and does not break dictionaries as i wrote in a previous comment. But the opposite, 2 equal objects that have different hash codes, is very bad. What i suggest is to make the `GetHashCode` more tolerant- that is, 2 different objects with different `Parent`s will have the same hash code (which ignores the `Parent`), and that's ok.

Comment: Yes, I know that, in fact that's exactly what I just told you, but that's not what you're suggesting.  By suggesting people override either `GetHashCode` or `Equals` but not the other, you create situations in which two objects are equal according to `Equals` but not equal according to `GetHashCode`.  That's very bad, and that's exactly what you are suggesting in your answer.  You shouldn't do that.  There is even a compiler warning for doing that as it has such a high probability of being incorrect code.

Comment: Edited to avoid confusion. When you think on this, every time you use a `IEqualityComparer` you can break the dictionary... I think that's a good solution for the OP's specific problem.

Comment: It is still wrong, and bad, for several reasons.  First, `Equals` will, if not overridden, use reference equality, not value equality, so overriding `GetHashCode` as you've shown and not overriding `Equals` won't result in the behavior you described.

Comment: As the OP put it, in his context overriding `Equals` is the same as `ReferenceEquals`. Generally i don't recommend such thing and i wrote it, i'm just trying to solve his private dilemma.

Comment: If you don't override `Equals` the implementation in `object` will be used.  It uses reference equality.  As I'm telling you, your solution *doesn't* solve his problem.  It simply results in a program that won't work, and for very confusing reasons.

Comment: I don't understand why it won't work, as long that `GetHashCode` is more tolerant. If so, implementing `IEqualityComparer` will not work too. By the way, get a little correction.

Comment: The whole point is that if you only override one, `GetHashCode` **wouldn't be more tolerant**.  It would be independent, and as a result wouldn't work.  You would need to override both, and as I said before, you should always be overriding both (or nether) in virtually every single situation, including this one.

Comment: I wrote to make it more tolerant. Please take a look on the edited answer. What i say is, you can make `Equals` differ but it must be less tolerant, just like you do in `IEqualityComparer`. Anyway, thanks for warning about possible confusion.