# C# Create a hash for a byte array or image

Tags: c#, .net, image, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I generate a hashcode from a byte array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340/how-do-i-generate-a-hashcode-from-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

In C#, I need to create a Hash of an image to ensure it is unique in storage.

I can easily convert it to a byte array, but unsure how to proceed from there.

Are there any classes in the .NET framework that can assist me, or is anyone aware of some *efficient* algorithms to create such a unique hash?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's plenty of hashsum providers in .NET which create cryptographic hashes - which satisifies your condition that they are unique (for most purposes collision-proof). They are all *extremely* fast and the hashing definitely won't be the bottleneck in your app unless you're doing it a trillion times over.

Personally I like SHA1:

```
public static string GetHashSHA1(this byte[] data)
{
    using (var sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        return string.Concat(sha1.ComputeHash(data).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
    }
}
```

Even when people say one method might be slower than another, it's all in relative terms. A program dealing with images definitely won't notice the microsecond process of generating a hashsum.

And regarding collisions, for most purposes this is also irrelevant. Even "obsolete" methods like MD5 are still highly useful in most situations. Only recommend not using it when the security of your system *relies* on preventing collisions.

Comment: Rex I'm sure you are aware of this, but as @AdamRobinson noted, no hash (including .NET cryptographic hashes such as SHA1) can ensure uniqueness; Not as long as the hash is a many-to-one mapping i.e. if there are fewer possible hashcodes than possible inputs.

Comment: @Spike0xff in software when we say "unique", it is understood to mean "unique enough". I don't see any indication that anyone in this thread is confused about that.

Comment: My concern isn't just with people who post, but with everybody who reads, and I don't think you'll necessarily see any indications if they are confused. And I think you mean "I hope it will be understood to mean" because that isn't the definition in the dictionary, nor is it the way I mean it or understand it. Maybe you can cite a reputable source?

Comment: @Spike0xff in any case, there's absolutely no chance in the lifetime of mankind any software will find by chance two identical hashes of 128-bits. So it's really ok to think "unless someone cracks the algorithm, this is unique".

Comment: @CamiloMartin Even at the time of your post, that was already not true: http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: @tstark81 "unless someone cracks the algorithm" - one can say this counts as MD5 being broken as an algorithm - also, normally you provide SHA-1 and MD5 hashes.

Comment: Why the result of this code for same images is a different in X86 and X64 ?

Comment: If you need to do this in a loop, don't create a new SHA1 object every time you need to hash, create it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 15):

The part of [Rex M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800469/50776) about using SHA1 to generate a hash is a good one (MD5 is also a popular option).  zvolkov's suggestion about not constantly creating new crypto providers is also a good one (as is the suggestion about using CRC if speed is more important than virtually-guaranteed uniqueness.

However, do *not* use [Encoding.UTF8.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) to convert a byte[] into a string (unless of course you know from context that it is valid UTF8).  For one, it will [reject invalid surogates](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/07/226306.aspx).  A method guaranteed to always give you a valid string from a byte[] is [Convert.ToBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, you're quite right there. In fact that's what I always do, but I threw down that sample off the top of my head and did the first byte[]-to-string that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jonathan, thanks for the edit Rex

Answer (score 6):

Creating new instance of SHA1CryptoServiceProvider every time you need to compute a hash is NOT fast at all. Using the same instance is pretty fast.

Still I'd rather do one of the many CRC algorithms instead of a cryptographic hash as hash functions designed for cryptography don't work too well for very small hash sizes (32 bit) which is what you want for your GetHash() override (assuming that's what you want).

Check this link out for one example of computing CRC in C#: http://sanity-free.org/134/standard_crc_16_in_csharp.html

P.S. the reason you want your hash to be small (16 or 32 bit) is so you can compare them FAST (that was the whole point of having hashes, remember?). Having hash represented by a 256-bit long value encoded as string is pretty insane in terms of performance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of the standard hashing algorithms, but hashing can't technically guarantee uniqueness. Hashing is designed to be a relatively fast and/or small token to be able to see if one piece of data likely is the same as the other. It's fully possible for entirely different sets of data to produce the same hash, though being able to produce these algorithmically is very hard.

All of that aside, for checking likely identity, MD5 is fairly fast. SHA is more reliable (MD5 has been hacked, so shouldn't be use for security), but it's also slower.