# What's the best way to save movie objects inside other files and associate them with the ones in the actual collection?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reference

I have a collection of `Movie` objects in a `HashSet<Movie>`. Movie type has properties such has `Name`, `Year`, `Length`, `Genre`, etc.

I also has user profiles stored in individual files. I want to have each user to have a number of favorite movies.

But I am not sure how to "connect"/reference these movies inside the user profiles.

Should I just rely on names?

What's the best way to store the favorite movies in these individual user profiles? I can't think of any other than using names, but this feels like a fragile way. Also movie names are not unique. There are some with the same names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hoping to link your `Movie` objects to another object, that I'm assuming are saved out for persistence, then you'd probably want to have some sort of unique identifier (`Guid` probably) that is associated with the `Movie` class.

The `User` class would then have a list of `Guid`s that represent the movies connected as favorites (or you can preload this with the actual movie objects)

Comment: Thanks but how can I generate them? What if the name of the movies change later on? Because sometimes they do.

Comment: When you create the movie object, in the constructor, do something like `id = Guid.NewGuid()` (`Guid` is in the `System` namespace). Only generate the id though if you are making a brand new movie object. You will be able to change the other properties, but as long as you don't change the Guid, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I get the from a website that I parse, so I will know if there is a new movie that's not in my existing list in memory and if so, generate a new guid like you said. But are guids easy to store? Because it will have stuff like UserA: Movie001 -> RatingHeGave, IsFavoriteMovie, etc so I wonder if guids are a huge overhead.

Comment: No significant overhead, Guids can be stored as strings like this: F3FAD7C4-3845-4A7A-9021-CC6301B107A6

Comment: Thanks, lastly btw I use serialization. They would be compatible with xml serializers I guess, right?

Comment: Yep, it will end up stored as a string like above and read back in properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the below approach is the best, but have you considered generating a hash value from the byte array that is your movie (when saved to disk or database)?

You can find some ideas on how to do that [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340/how-do-i-generate-a-hashcode-from-a-byte-array-in-c).

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of hash values but wasn't sure if that's a good idea. Also is there a good hash algorithm I can use for this?

Comment: Based on what you said about the names changing, this might not be a good idea because then the hash values will change

Comment: My suggestion was to use the video byte stream as the source for the hash.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, my list of movies are just like on imdb, I don't have any actual movies on disk :O