# HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 same images with different Image properties and file properties (e.g. CreationDate, etc.). When I calculate hash, I get different hashes. Is there any way to skip such properties and calculate hash to get same hashes?

Awaiting help.
Thanks

Comment: Added one edge case that may or may not matter to your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [read the image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352061/fastest-way-to-convert-image-to-byte-array) into a byte array and [hash that byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340/how-do-i-generate-a-hashcode-from-a-byte-array-in-c).

That way, differences in meta-data would not be considered.

Since the 2D data is read into a 1D array, you can construct cases where two images with different dimensions have the same hash. For example, consider a 2x2 image and a 4x1 image. R means red and B means blue (just to pick two colors)

```
RB
BR
```

and

```
RBBR
```

Both would have the same hash code. If that matters to you, prepend (or append) the width and height of the image to the byte array before hashing.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any solution for video formats?

Comment: There's a lot more data involved, but the same basic approach. You could probably grab a few seconds of data from the middle of the video and use that if performance is key. I would not grab the beginning or end as some videos have the same lead-in (e.g. if the same company made them)